# Title of HTML page & favicon is not getting displayed on Server?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Friends, I am working on making a website in which there is an Index.html page, I have defined the title of that page to be for example "Some title here" and a favicon, both of them are getting displayed on localhost but not on server.

I am using Asp.net MVC but the page is basic html i.e. not razor view or anything. The code of  tag of that page is

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Some title here</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../gfiwebsite/img/favicon.png">
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
<!-- Plugin CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
```

**Added**
I found that when I hit the temp url of the server that I am using, I am able to see the favicon and title but when I map it to my domain which I have purchased from godaddy, the favicon and title just goes away, any idea why?
Any thoughts?

Comment: for `favicon` try this: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/gfiwebsite/img/favicon.png">` get icon from root.

Comment: Hey I got something more to share. I am editing the question

Comment: Are you sure you've put everything between `<head></head>` tags?

Comment: @Babydead yes, I have edited the code above

Answer (score 0):

You can use an url helper to generate the link to the favicon. Assuming that you have placed the file inside `img/favicon.png`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/img/favicon.png")">
```

The `~` indicates the root of your website.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is with the link, it is being correctly displayed on server with temp url, but when I am pointing it to my domain that I have purchased from godaddy, then it gives error. If you can come on chat, I can show you the exact scenario

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Once you have we can talk if this doesn't help.

Comment: I tried your solution, it makes no difference to what I have currently

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net, elements aren't the same as in regular .html files.

Do you have the following syntax at the top of your page?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Default Title" %>
```

If you do, you should try to remove the title attribute and see if it works now. If you don't, try doing it ;) (Been a while since I've worked in classic asp myself)

Do you have `<head runat="server">`? Because `<head>` doesn't work.

`ASP.NET` does *not* use the same flat html as a regular .html file.

If you really want to work without razor and such, this might be an interesting read:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/specifying-the-title-meta-tags-and-other-html-headers-in-the-master-page-cs

**edit:** You said it works on a temporary domain but not on Godaddy? Are you 100% sure that Godaddy doesn't have any strange caching enabled?
I have run into this issue a great many times... Webhosts introducing certain types of caching that nearly always interfere with these things.

Also, open your console, and go to "network". Make sure you leave it open and make sure "disable caching" is checked. Now, refresh the website.